# .htpasswd on a rewritten URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I was tasked with securing a poorly-written PHP site which uses basic rewrite rules to create pretty URLs.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?mod_name=$0 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I'd like to protect the "/admin/" rewrite (index.php?mod_name=admin) and its children (admin/orders, admin/projects, etc) with a standard .htpasswd, as the security written by the original code monkey was terrible and can be easily bypassed... I'd like to do this rather than re-engineering the entire site from scratch, since even the site's php password encryption and storage is terrible.

Is this possible within a .htaccess file in the root? Adding an "admin" directory for real and using the standard method makes it so that it overrides the rewrite rule in the root... showing a blank directory...

I tried doing a rewrite rule in the "real" /admin/ directory to point it back at the parent directory's index.php (with the query string) but that results in a 404 OR just a blank directory. It isn't redirecting to the parent's index.php w/ query string... tried changing the RewriteBase, tried changing the RewriteRule to include {$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}... nothing works.

Comment: And you can't just rebuild the security? Instead of building a new door in front of the broken door, you maybe should fix the broken door instead.

Comment: they have a very limited budget, and the code is a mess... I kind of don't want to even touch it.

Comment: The solution with a pseudo `/admin/` folder with auth is possible but not useful, because one could directly access the url `index.php?mod_name=admin`, and the auth in the pseudo admin folder will be bypassed... The entry point into the app is index.php and may be you should hook into there at the beginning something like `if (mod_name==admin) { do_auth(); }`. I cannot think of a possible solution with htaccess...

Comment: @Zimmi that's a great point I hadn't considered. Thanks!